# Verb Tense - Past or Past Perfect?

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

Just wondering which verb tense would be correct. It's fiction written in the past tense.

1) James fired his gun over the couch we hid behind.

2) James fired his gun over the couch we’d hidden behind.

3) James fired his gun over the couch we were hiding behind.

Thanks!

Comment: They're all fine. The first one *could* be used to mean *the couch we **habitually** hid behind*, even if we weren't doing it on this specific occasion (and in contrived contexts, feasibly even #2 could do something like that). But it doesn't *have* to carry that implication.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers, but I'd add that #2 could also refer to our having hidden behind the couch briefly on one occasion separate from the time James fired his gun. Only #3 makes it clear (to me) that James was shooting while we were behind the couch.